# Why this charcter conversion Happens?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I'm trying to submit a html form, Contents of the form are in mixed language like combination of english and Thai or english arabic etc but english is always there.

lets say I submitted form with

> stackoverflow,การพัฒนา

Now at server (Java Servlet)  Text received as

> stackoverflow,à¸à¸²à¸£à¸à¸±à¸à¸à¸²

I'm setting JSP page Encoding as UTF-8 in page directive.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Please feel free to ask if anything else is required.

Here is the Root JSP which is included in all other jsp (layout kind of structure )

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/util.tld" prefix="util" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/excel.tld" prefix="ms" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/license.tld" prefix="license" %>
```

Edit:
in response to comment below:

```
public void setEmailAddresses(String val) {
    System.out.println(val);
    emailAddresses = val;
}
public String getEmailAddresses() {
    System.out.println(val);
    return emailAddresses;
}
```

Comment: did you try to set your `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in your servlet? Can you show us your servlet?

Comment: I'm using Struts 1.1, therefore no Servlet exists, but edited the Question So that you can see the JSP where I'm doing so.

Comment: Can you show us your server part?

Comment: I'm not able to follow you, can you please elaborate yourself?

Comment: Show us the method that you use to to print the text, your Java Servlet.

Comment: currently i'm displaying Text from action bean ( set and get ) methods. this bean is carrying html form data to the action class's doPerform method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters conversion happens due to following:

1. Struts 1.1 only supports "ISO-8859-1" character encoding.

Solution:

1. Upgrade to Struts 1.2 or above.( recommended)
2. Use Servlet instead of action beans.

Answer (score 1):

Include Uni-code Meta Header to support characters other thn English Language

For HTML 5 pages:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
```

For older HTML 4.0.1 pages, use this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: I already answered this question and Solution is answer Provided by me. (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Try insert

<`meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

into `<head></head>` pair tags.

or try this one on ur jsp file like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

 <html>

<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
 <%--Contents--%>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here You can see It is already done:




<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>



<head>
    <!-- Charset-->
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Well It is not resolving issue?

Comment: maybe u need response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); look at this one http://balusc.blogspot.jp/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest

Comment: I did as you suggested but No luck.
Can you tell me where to specify URIencoding for Resin server?

Comment: u mean tomcat's uriencoding??

Comment: I know about Tomcat's URIencoding location but Want to know about Resin's!

Comment: <resin xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin">
  <character-encoding>utf-8</character-encoding>
  ...

</resin>